# Jenkins pipeline: how to check for remote branch without starting a shell

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have a Jenkins Pipeline Library method called `branchExists.groovy` that checks if a branch exists in a remote (not local!) repository.

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def call(String repoUrl, String branchName) {
    // Use git ls-remote to verify branch existence
    def sout = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "#!/bin/bash\ngit ls-remote --heads ${repoUrl} refs/heads/${branchName}").trim()
    return sout.size() != 0
}
```

So, as you can see, a Bash shell is started to run the command `git ls-remote`. To run a shell, the method *must* run inside the context of a `node{}` block in the Pipeline, even if I don't do anything else on that node.

Is there a way in Jenkins Pipeline parlance, to check remote branches without needing to run a shell command, and thereby not making it necessary to occupy a `node{}`?

EDIT: maybe it's good to know that the Git server is Atlassian Bitbucket Server, so maybe I could use the Bitbucket API? Or would that still require a node?

---

#### Why do I want to avoid occupying a node?

The reason why I am concerned about not occupying a node, is because of flyweight/lightweight vs heavyweight executors. See https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012808951-Pipeline-Difference-between-flyweight-and-heavyweight-Executors

> *Flyweight executors are just threads*, running inside of the Jenkins master’s JVM. *Flyweight executors are unlimited* and will be created automatically when needed, unlike heavyweight executors, which are limited based on their node’s configuration.
>
> Every Pipeline script itself runs on the master using a flyweight executor (i.e. Java thread). *Pipeline steps such as sh and bat will execute on a heavyweight executor when enclosed in a node block*, so in a well-designed Pipeline where complicated logic happens only in those steps, the flyweight executor should be idling while steps run on remote agents for most of the build.

Flyweight executors won't block the build queue and won't be blocked by the build queue. If all heavyweight executors are saturated then my pipeline won't continue until an executor becomes available to run `git ls-remote`.

Comment: My understanding is that all the sh commands are ran on Master anyway, so in order to keep my resources to the minimum I would make a dedicated (container) slave for trivial commands.  As alternative node('master') would force the whole execution on master - but this is not always a good idea.

Comment: It's not just about running on "master" (Jenkins please get rid of that racially charged word ASAP!), it's also that, as long as your code doesn't run on a node, it runs in a so-called "lightweight executor", which means that it isn't blocking other jobs in the build queue AND if all executors are taken by other jobs, the pipeline won't continue until an executor becomes available.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! It seems that I cannot edit my comment to replace the old Jenkins terminology. :(

Comment: Don't worry, my comment between brackets wasn't aimed at you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find, the answer is no.  I can't find anything in Jenkins itself that might provide the functionality.

Even if you were to try talking to the BitBucket API, you would still need a node to handle that communication.

The only way that I think you might be able to achieve the functionality you're looking for would be to write a custom Java or Groovy library that you could incorporate into your Jenkinsfile that would either talk to git natively through a library like [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) or talk to BitBucket natively like [bitbucket-rest](https://github.com/cdancy/bitbucket-rest).

Comment: Are you sure about the Bitbucket Server API? That would be a REST call with a JSON reply, and parsing that JSON can simply be done in a Java thread. We've done someting similar with the Jira API. Something like `def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'GET', url: jiraRestEndpointWithParameters, authentication: jiraAuthentication` and then `def jsonObj = readJSON text: response.content`. That's pure Groovy, I have checked where we use that method and it's definitely _not_ inside a `node` block.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call a 3 line method in the `vars` folder in a Pipeline Library a "custom Java or Groovy library" tbh...

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkinsfile is a DSL based on Groovy. Jenkins Administrators can develop Groovy scripts and test them in Jenkins' scripting engine https://jenkins.example.com/script. Scripts run this way don't occupy a node, but note that this implies that environment variables are not available as in a build job. You can get at them however with a little trick. Your token stored in $BITBUCKET_KEY is collected with the getToken() method in the example below...

The Atlassian BitBucket Server has a REST API which supports various methods on resources, and filters. This resource is the one you need to process:

**/rest/api/latest/projects/${a_team}/repos/${a_repo}/branches**

Below is Groovy code to do that.

```java
/* groovylint-disable CompileStatic */
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

List branches = []

def getToken() {
  instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
  globalNodeProperties = instance.getGlobalNodeProperties()
  iccKey= 'not set'
  globalNodeProperties.each {
    envVars = it.getEnvVars()
    if (envVars.get('BITBUCKET_KEY') != null) {
      iccKey = envVars.get('BITBUCKET_KEY')
    }
  }
  return iccKey.getBytes('UTF-8').encodeBase64()
}

Boolean isBranch(String a_team, String a_repo, String a_branch) {
  URL url = new URL("https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/latest/projects/${a_team}/repos/${a_repo}/branches?limit=100")
  HttpURLConnection  connection = url.openConnection()
  connection.requestMethod = 'GET'
  connection.setRequestProperty('Authorization', 'Basic ' + token)
  connection.connect()
  String response = connection.content.text
  def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
  List branchNames = []
  List branchesList = json.values
  branchesList.each { its ->
    // add the short name of the branch
    try {
      if (its.displayId == a_branch) {
        branchNames.add(its.displayId)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      println('An error occurred: ' + error.message)
    }
  }

  //return branchNames

  if (branchNames.size >= 1) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false 
  }
}

println(isBranch('MY_BITBUCKET_PROJECT','my_git_repo','bugfix/blabla'))
```